# Alfresco: index creation stuck when enabling "Content indexing"

Tags: alfresco, solr4

I am trying to index a Alfresco <del>4.0.d</del> 5.0.d Community Repository (Alfresco Solr):

- About 500.000 Documents
- Repo-Size about 80GB

Metadata Indexing only: no problems: index is ready in about an hour.

Enabling Content Indexing too: The Solr Index seems to get stuck. After about 4 hours the Solr Webinterface is showing that no more transactions are left, but still the Index isn't marked as ready, and Solr keeps trying to create/update the index, when letting the indexer run. Stopped Indexing after about 12 hours, no progress shown in Solr Webinterface. Index Size kept growing all the time.

The "Troubleshooting Solr Index" tips from Alfresco Docs didn't make any difference.

I have enabled Debugging in Solr, and i am getting no obvious errors in there (no memory errors, no obvious errors at all). Only thing i see in the log files: Solr seems to try to Index the same Alfresco Transaction IDs over and over (see log excerpt, these lines are popping up over and over).

- Any Idea how i can track down the cause of this?
- Is it possible to find the Documents in the Repository belonging to the Transaction IDs?
- Can some specific Transactions be excluded from indexing at all?

Thanks, Max

### Log excerpt

```
2016-03-10 00:52:15,145 INFO  [org.alfresco.solr.tracker.AclTracker] Scanning Acl change sets ...
2016-03-10 00:52:15,145 INFO  [org.alfresco.solr.tracker.AclTracker] .... none found after lastTxCommitTime 1457481600850
2016-03-10 00:52:15,145 INFO  [org.alfresco.solr.tracker.AclTracker] total number of acls updated: 0
2016-03-10 00:52:15,145 INFO  [org.alfresco.solr.tracker.AbstractTracker] ... Running ContentTracker for core [archive].
2016-03-10 00:52:15,146 INFO  [org.alfresco.solr.SolrInformationServer] .... registered Searchers for archive = 1
2016-03-10 00:52:15,146 INFO  [org.alfresco.solr.Cloud] Running query FTSSTATUS:Dirty OR FTSSTATUS:New
2016-03-10 00:52:15,146 INFO  [org.alfresco.solr.tracker.ContentTracker] total number of docs with content updated: 0
2016-03-10 00:52:15,146 INFO  [org.alfresco.solr.tracker.AbstractTracker] ... Running MetadataTracker for core [archive].
2016-03-10 00:52:15,147 INFO  [org.alfresco.solr.SolrInformationServer] .... registered Searchers for archive = 1
2016-03-10 00:52:15,155 INFO  [org.alfresco.solr.Cloud] Running query TXID:1 AND TXCOMMITTIME:1399544992347
2016-03-10 00:52:15,155 INFO  [org.alfresco.solr.tracker.MetadataTracker] Verified first transaction and timestamp in index
2016-03-10 00:52:15,156 INFO  [org.alfresco.solr.tracker.MetadataTracker] Verified last transaction timestamp in index less than or equal to that of repository.
2016-03-10 00:52:15,161 INFO  [org.alfresco.solr.tracker.MetadataTracker] Scanning transactions ...
2016-03-10 00:52:15,161 INFO  [org.alfresco.solr.tracker.MetadataTracker] .... from Transaction [id=947618, commitTimeMs=1457521663509, updates=2, deletes=2]
2016-03-10 00:52:15,161 INFO  [org.alfresco.solr.tracker.MetadataTracker] .... to Transaction [id=947654, commitTimeMs=1457524857746, updates=1, deletes=0]
2016-03-10 00:52:15,164 INFO  [org.alfresco.solr.tracker.MetadataTracker] Scanning transactions ...
2016-03-10 00:52:15,164 INFO  [org.alfresco.solr.tracker.MetadataTracker] .... from Transaction [id=947654, commitTimeMs=1457524857746, updates=1, deletes=0]
2016-03-10 00:52:15,165 INFO  [org.alfresco.solr.tracker.MetadataTracker] .... to Transaction [id=947655, commitTimeMs=1457524858267, updates=2, deletes=1]
2016-03-10 00:52:15,180 INFO  [org.alfresco.solr.tracker.MetadataTracker] Scanning transactions ...
2016-03-10 00:52:15,180 INFO  [org.alfresco.solr.tracker.MetadataTracker] .... none found after lastTxCommitTime 1457524858267
2016-03-10 00:52:15,180 INFO  [org.alfresco.solr.tracker.MetadataTracker] total number of docs with metadata updated: 0
2016-03-10 00:52:17,513 DEBUG [org.alfresco.solr.content.SolrContentUrlBuilder] Appending SOLR metadata: tenant - _DEFAULT_
2016-03-10 00:52:17,513 DEBUG [org.alfresco.solr.content.SolrContentUrlBuilder] Appending SOLR metadata: tenant - _DEFAULT_
2016-03-10 00:52:17,513 DEBUG [org.alfresco.solr.content.SolrContentUrlBuilder] Appending SOLR metadata: tenant - _DEFAULT_
2016-03-10 00:52:17,513 DEBUG [org.alfresco.solr.content.SolrContentUrlBuilder] Appending SOLR metadata: dbId - 124123
2016-03-10 00:52:17,513 DEBUG [org.alfresco.solr.content.SolrContentUrlBuilder] Converted SOLR metadata to URL: solr://
```

---

Edit: Adding Screenshots:

[Solr Webadmin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qNUmS.png)

[Solr Health Report for Workspace Spaces Store](https://i.stack.imgur.com/idHsm.png)

Answer (score 1):

How did you check if solr is marked as ready?
Are you aware that there is a separate index for the trash (archive) and the "real" repository (workspace)? The log is showing output for the archive tracker.
Additionally it may help to downsize the tracker config and only allow one thread per tracker and or to disable the trash indexing.

### Index Reports

Have you checked Index reports? s. https://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Alfresco_And_SOLR#Direct_URLs. You may need to import the repository certificates in your browser to be able to access the solr user interface and the alfresco solr reports

Could you please create and attach a alfresco-solr general report

```
http://<alfrescoserver>/solr/admin/cores?action=REPORT&wt=xml
```

and a a summary report

```
http://<alfrescoserver>/solr/admin/cores?action=SUMMARY&wt=xml
```

?

### Transactions and nodes

You can check the transactions in the database. The log is telling you all the requird infos. In your snippet I can't find log entries reindexing the same node as you told but e.g. "Transaction id=947655" means the row in alf_transaction with id=947655. To find all nodes from a distinct transaction_id you can just

```
select * from alf_node where transaction_id=947655
```

It is not possible to skip distinct transactions but you can attach the `cm:indexControl` to nodes you don't want to index. Please check http://docs.alfresco.com/4.0/concepts/admin-indexes.html

Comment: I checked the Index Status with the Solr Admin Webapp.

Comment: The Index for the Archive Store is shown as current (green Checkmark), the Index for the Contentstore never gets current.

Comment: And the Index Size of the Conentstore is growing constantly, even after 12 hours and even Solr shows: 0 Transactions remaining.

Comment: I know about cm:indexControl. Will have to identify the possibly problematic Docs though before i can apply the cm:IndexControl ;-) Thanks for the SQL snippet, will check, if it leads to some problematic Docs in the Repo.

Comment: Will post the mentioned Solr xml reports as soon as i have access to the devel servers again (probably in a few days). In the meantime: Thanks much!

Comment: What do you mean with "I checked the Index Status with the Solr Admin Webapp"? Which URL? Do you use Enterprise Edition? Which exactly Alfresco Version are you using? At least in 4.x versions SOLR trackers and cores have nonsense default config wich may result in too many threads waiting and queuing up. In most cases it's a tuning job by downsizing config if you don't have unlimited hardware resources on the repository tier.

Comment: Alfresco Version is 5.0.d Community (Sorry wrote a false 4.0.d in the header of my question). Solr Admin App: https://myhost.xxx.xx:8443/solr4/#/alfresco

Comment: Added Screenshots for Solr Webadmin and Solr Health report to my edited question. Both Screenshots are showing the status at the time, the indexer was running, approx. a month ago.